# Does SQL Server support nested transactions?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, nested

I wondered if SQL Server supports nested transactions?

I can see other questions similar.

Also - How do I know if I am in a nested transaction?

This may seem a strange question .. but ..
in SSMS I might have run the command `BEGIN TRANSACTION` more than once by accident .. for example .. Will this mean that I need to run the `COMMIT TRANSACTION` more than once to finalise the transaction?

I'm thinking nested transactions should generally be avoided.

```
SELECT
    [Initial Assess -  Sweating], 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM
    Clinical.SAASCaseCards 
GROUP BY
    [Initial Assess -  Sweating]

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE Clinical.SAASCaseCards 
SET [Initial Assess -  Sweating] = '1' 
WHERE [Initial Assess -  Sweating]= '01'

COMMIT TRANSACTION ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the global variable @@TRANCOUNT to see how this works.

If you run `select @@TRANCOUNT` and you have no transactions around you will get 0.

Each time `begin transaction` is run, @@TRANCOUNT increases by 1.
Each time `commit (transaction)` is run, @@TRANCOUNT decreases by 1. If that made @@TRANCOUNT to be set to 0, then the transaction(s) are *indeed* committed.

On the other hand, a `rollback (transaction)` will set @@TRANCOUNT to 0 and roll back all changes regardless of the value of @@TRANCOUNT at that time.

So, there is no functional nesting. There is only this counter in order to allow different modules to make their own transaction handling.

I recommend [Erland Sommerskog's article](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) for further reading.

Comment: Here is another excellent article on the myth of nested transactions. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/

Comment: Nice one @Sean, actually *your* link is the one I was trying to find, but hadn't in my fav list!

Answer (score 0):

Yes transaction can be nested. But once your outer transaction fails, your inner transaction will be rollback too.

[Nested transactions in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527855/nested-transactions-in-sql-server)

Comment: Nested transactions are a myth. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/

Answer (score -2):

So far as I am aware, transactions cannot be nested.